# Computing Theoretical ACF of ARIMA

Tags: r

I did a simulation using `arima.sim` for a `(1,1,1)` process with `ar` parameter `0.8` and `ma` parameter `0.3`.  I have the results and I want to compare to the theoretical correlation values for this process.  I'm not sure how to handle the differencing (d=1), because usually I use `ARMAacf` for computing such values, but that only has the (p,q) inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Then just use `acf()` for autocorrelation or `pacf()` for partial autocorrelation.